# Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored

Tags: c#, mysql

I followed [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/a499467f-2be0-4300-abd3-8d67ce5e19f6/sql-with-parameters-using-idbcommand) thread trying to set connection to `MySQL` and run prepared statements (with minor difference that in the thread they are talking about `Postgresql`). This is what I've done:

```
  IDbConnection cnx = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
  cnx.Open();
  IDbCommand cmd = cnx.CreateCommand();

  string sql = "insert into table1 (column2) values ($1)";

  cmd.CommandText = sql;

  IDbDataParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
  param.DbType = DbType.AnsiString;
  param.ParameterName = "1";
  param.Value = "Parameter Value";

  cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But as a result, I get thie error message:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection.Add (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0

I should add, that I specifically use `IDbConnection`, because later I want to reuse this code for other databases and this approach should save me hundreds lines of code.

Comment: If you are really after a good level of abstraction from the underlying database then I suggest to use an ORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net)

Comment: No, I'm not yet at that point, but becoming closer to it. However, when I reach it, I think I will have to make my own ORM closely related to my application objects.

Comment: It is up to you. But probably the little time you need to discover how to use Dapper will repay itself a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@` as the name decorator rather than `$`

```
string sql = "insert into table1 (column2) values (@value)";
...
cmd.Parameters.Add("@value", MySqlDbType.AnsiString).Value = "Parameter Value";
```

Comment: Is it possible not to hard code `MySqlDbType.AnsiString` to the procedure? This approach will not generalize on other databases without some extra routine coding,

Comment: Pass, you will have to try with the DbType enum and see if it works

Comment: Also note some dbs have different decorators, E.g. Oracle uses `:name` others just a `?`